# .Net CAD2010:Occurs an error when load cuix file

Tags: c#, cad

I create a menu(.cuix file),and want to load it,But it occurs an error when execute the SendStringToExecute function.Please comment to help me, thanks.

I have searched many solutions in internet,But all of solutions are not work.

```
Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", 0);
Application.SetSystemVariable("FILEDIA", 0);
ed.Document.SendStringToExecute("cuiload " + cuiFileName + " ", false, false, false);   // eNoDocument error
Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", 1);
Application.SetSystemVariable("FILEDIA", 1);
```

I will be so apreciated if someone can help me.Please comment to help me.

Comment: what does `cuiFileName` store?

Comment: It is the path of .cuix file:"D:\\RibbonTool\\Debug32\\TX_Menu.cuix".I want to load it,but failed.